# Outlook script that runs when email is received works only when I transfer the new mail to myself

Tags: vba, outlook

I made a code that would take an incomming email in a specific folder (First a rule is created in order to move the mail to the folder and then the script is launched).

The problem is that the rule is working (it moves the mail to the folder), but the script isn't.

The thing is that when I take the new mail and transfer it to myself (My email is also in the receivers in the rules), the script is correctly working.

Here is the beginning of the code that I believe may be wrong.

```
Sub Script(item As Outlook.MailItem) 


Dim strMailID As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace

strMailID = item.EntryID
Set objNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMail = objNamespace.GetItemFromID(strMailID)
Dim objpf As MAPIFolder

If objMail.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add an event listener to the default local Inbox, it worked with Outlook 2016.

This code will add an event listener to the default local Inbox. Action will be placed upon incoming emails. You need to add actions you need in the code below:

```
                Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items 
                Private Sub Application_Startup() 
                Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
                Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace 
                Set olApp = Outlook.Application 
                Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
                ' default local Inbox
                Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 
                End Sub
                Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 

                On Error Goto ErrorHandler 
                 Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem 
                 If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
                Set Msg = item 
                ' ******************
                ' do something here
                ' ******************
                End If
                ProgramExit: 
                  Exit Sub
                ErrorHandler: 
                MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description 
                Resume ProgramExit 
                End Sub
```

After pasting the code in ThisOutlookSession module, you must restart Outlook.

Comment: Thank You , I tried this code but the macro isn't appearing in the rule anymore.

Comment: You could try this url:  https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/. In addition, Is it useful when email is received in the upper code.

Comment: Nevermind I just realised that the script launches itself when Outlook launches so I don't need to call it in the rule is that right ? Furthermore, do I need to check the news mails as read, so that the script doesn't run on the unread mail at the next launch of outlook ?Thank You very much

Comment: Yes,you don't need to call it. because "Application_Startup()" will Automatic execution macro when Outlook launches. You could check the news mails as read.

Comment: Thank You very much, it works like a charm and way faster than before  !